# Prevent Git Push live master from changing file permission and ownership

Tags: git, digital-ocean

I have been battling with this for days now... each time I do `git push live master` (using git post hook) ... Remote file permissions and ownership are being changed every time back to the default which would make pages on the website throw a 500 error. I usually get around this by running `sudo chown -Rf www-data:www-data /var/www/<Website-Root-Folder>` but I want this permanently fixed, so I don't have to do this every time.

I have done the following, which I found here: [Permissions with Git Post-Receive](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/permissions-with-git-post-receive)

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data root  // As I'm doing my push using the root user.
```

Sorry, I'm new to git, linux, Not sure what else to do. Any help in making this work without me having to run this `sudo chown -Rf www-data:www-data /var/www/<Website-Root-Folder>` after every push will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is not a good idea to add the `www-data` user to the `root` group, to remove it : `deluser www-data root`

Comment: I got this `/usr/sbin/deluser: The user www-data is not a member of group root'.` ...

Comment: ok, run `groups www-data` to confirm the `root` group does not appear there

Comment: I got this `www-data : www-data` after running `groups www-data`

Comment: it's good : user `www-data` is only in `www-data` group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote a script, which, at some point, executes `git checkout` -- or an equivalent command -- that actually creates and updates files in your target folder.

You should make it so that this command is run with the user you want, for example :

```
sudo -u www-data git checkout ...
```

You may need to set the access rights on the repo itself so that user `www-data` can *read* the repo :

- if your repo has `r` access for all users, you have nothing more to do,
- you can decide to set the group of all files in that specific repo to `www-data` :

  ```
  # in your post-receive script :
  chrgp www-data -R .
  ```
- or set the setgid bit on that repo's directory, so that files and directories created within automatically inherit this directory's group (instead of the user's group) :

  ```
  # run once on your server, as root user :
  $ chmod -R g+s /path/to/repo.git
  $ chgrp -R www-data /path/to/repo.git

  $ ls -ld /path/to/repo.git
  drwxrwsr-x 9 root www-data 4096 janv. 13 14:20 repo.git
        ^
  # notice the 's' in the access rights
  ```

Comment: Sorry, speaking of /path/to/repo.git ... is it the Remote Repo or the Bridge Repo (i.e the empty repo that handles the git push live master)

Comment: side note : I updated my answer : if your files and diredctories already have `r` access for all users, you don't have to set anything else

Comment: /path/to/repo.git : you placed your `post-receive` script within a copy of the repo on your server, it would be that repo.

Comment: I'm so beginner level with all this, sorry if I'm not getting you. I don't know how to check if all users has `r` access

Comment: `ls -ld /path/to/repo.git` : look at the first sequence of characters : `drwxr-xr-x` if the last `r` (3rd char from the end) and `x` (last char) are there, everyone has read access to that directory, and can inspect its content.

Comment: Search for "linux file permissions", on example post : https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/

Comment: in my post-receive file in /var/repo/site.git/hooks ... has this in it `#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/WEBSITEFOLDER --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f` ... That makes the  /path/to/repo.git you have been referring to /var/repo/site.git ? Sorry I'm trying to understand this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227283/discussion-between-kolawole-emmanuel-izzy-and-legec).

Comment: Well, I guess you gave up on me ... Thank you so much for your time @LeGEC

Comment: I'm mixing things up. Yes, the git repo is `/var/repo/site.git`, and you want www-data to have read access on the files within that directory. `ls -ld /var/repo/site.git` to see how accesses are set up on the directory itself, `ls -l /var/repo/site.git`  (without the `-d`) to see how access rules are set up on its content, etc ...